# Apache filename too long, client browser looks to be trying to download multiple files in one request

Tags: apache, browser

> File name too long: [client {CLIENT IP ADDRESS}:58749] AH00036: access to
>
> /wp-content,_plugins,_wp-file-upload,_vendor,_datetimepicker,_jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js,qver==4.6+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_sortable.min.js,qver==1.11.4+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_tabs.min.js,qver==1.11.4+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_accordion.min.js,qver==1.11.4.pagespeed.jc.zgb126SHUb.js
>
> failed (filesystem path
> '/home/{DOMAIN HOME DIR}/public_html/wp-content,_plugins,_wp-file-upload,_vendor,_datetimepicker,_jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js,qver==4.6+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_sortable.min.js,qver==1.11.4+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_tabs.min.js,qver==1.11.4+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_accordion.min.js,qver==1.11.4.pagespeed.jc.zgb126SHUb.js')

This strange error log has appeared a few times over the last few months and I can't make much sense of it.

It looks like the client browser is trying to access the url http://domain.com/wp-content,_plugins,_wp-file-upload,_vendor,_datetimepicker,_jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js,qver==4.6+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_sortable.min.js,qver==1.11.4+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_tabs.min.js,qver==1.11.4+wp-includes,_js,_jquery,_ui,_accordion.min.js,qver==1.11.4.pagespeed.jc.zgb126SHUb.js

Which isn't in the HTML at all, however there is:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-file-upload/vendor/datetimepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domain.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/sortable.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domain.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/tabs.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domain.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/accordion.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
```

It looks like the client browser is trying to request all of these files at once by adding "+" between them in one url.

I've never seen this before and over the last month haven't been able to find anything on Google.

One of the the clients browser was Chrome on Android 4.4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could also be a broken assets pipeline on the server side. Though indeed you should see the reference in the code in that case.

Comment: _“One of the the clients browser was Chrome on Android 4.4”_ – or at least pretended to be … Unless IP addresses or connection to actually logged in users prove otherwise, I would rather assume that this is perhaps some bot that tries to scan for common WP vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. The user contact my client and the error log is at the same time they said they were unable to use the site.

Comment: @arkascha thanks for your reply, i'm not familiar with what assets pipeline are but i'll read up on it

Comment: @arkascha I've taken a look and that seems to be a rails/nodejs - i'm running Apache/Wordpress, no special apache modules. What I find confusing is how this error occurs twice a month and each time a different user contacts my client saying there was a problem with the site. Any potential ideas what it could be would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An asset pipeline is a general approach to minify / combine many assets files to speed up delivery. It is not specific to any http server or similar but a general approach. It is widely used in CMS applications too, also those based on php and apache.

Comment: I expect you _did_ check your http servers error log file for the point in time when such error occurs?

Comment: Thanks so much for your thoughts, I can't seem to find a correlation in time but i'm going to have to investigate the files further as in the error it mentiones "pagespeed.jc" which seems to be for google's mod_pagespeed apache module - this isn't on the server